Executing SQL select against OGR datasource without listing every table
My aim is to filter and join multiple tables, then display as points in QGIS. I'd like to do this in a single vrt definition. My issue seems to be that if I don't define the tables in the SrcDataSource string, every table details gets returned prior to the SQL string executing. It's slow.
eg, this works
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="collar_points">
    <SrcDataSource>ODBC:acquire</SrcDataSource>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>EPSG:20355</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Best_Easting_DF" y="Best_Northing_DF"/>
    <SrcSQL>
            SELECT TOP 10 
                HOLEID, 
                Best_Easting_DF, 
                Best_Northing_DF 
            FROM dbo.COLLAR
    </SrcSQL>
</OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>

but very slow, looking through return of
ogrinfo --debug on "ODBC:acquire" -sql "SELECT TOP 10 HOLEID, Best_Easting_DF, Best_Northing_DF FROM dbo.COLLAR"

it lists every table first. eg
GDAL: Proxy driver FileGDB *not* registered due to ogr_FileGDB.dll not being found
GDAL: Proxy driver HANA *not* registered due to ogr_HANA.dll not being found
GDAL: Proxy driver KEA *not* registered due to gdal_KEA.dll not being found
OGR_ODBC: EstablishSession(DSN:"acquire", userid:"", password:"")
ODBC: SQLConnect(acquire)
ODBC: CatalogNameL: (null)
Schema name: (null)
OGR_ODBC: Table AcqCoordinates.CoordinateMethod has no identified FID column.

then every table in database, followed by the select statement
GDAL: GDALOpen(ODBC:acquire, this=000001BBE20A6130) succeeds as ODBC.
INFO: Open of `ODBC:acquire'
      using driver `ODBC' successful.
ODBC: ExecuteSQL(SELECT TOP 10 HOLEID, Best_Easting_DF, Best_Northing_DF FROM dbo.COLLAR) called.
OGR_ODBC: Table SELECT has no identified FID column.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 10
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
HOLEID: String (20.0)

All my permutations of incorporating the select statement into the connection string haven't worked, eg dialect statements etc.
I thought this would be a common use case, executing a select statement and generating points.

The SQL part is a common use case, but using ODBC connection is not so common. I think you can test the theory be converting the whole VRT datasource into for example GeoPackage and running corresponding SQL query against it.

Have you tried adding the table name into the data source, (ODBC:userid/password@dsn,schema.tablename(geometrycolname)) as highlighted in the doc as "Fetching the full definition of all tables in a complicated database can be quite time consuming, so the ability to restrict the set of tables accessed is primarily a performance issue."

That works actually, even if the table name isn't used in the SrcSQL (which I'd assumed it would) it still stops it returning everthing. Now onto why it doesn't like the rest of my SQL statement....
Thanks
